# Ошибка Responce [500] Python, как это исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

В общем отправляю запрос на сайт, и всё что получаю это Responce [500] или то что на картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
import json

def get_html(url, useragent = None, proxy=None):
    print("get_html")
    s = requests.Session()
    s.get("http://toto-info.co")

    pl = {"options": {"DrawingId": 628, "StartFrom": 0, "Count": 20, "SortField": "CouponCode", "SortDir": "ASC"}}

    res = s.post("http://old.toto-info.co/DataService.svc/GetMaxPrizeCoupons", headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 YaBrowser/17.3.1.840 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept-Language' : 'ru,en;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Connection': 'keep - alive',
            'Host': 'old.toto-info.co',
            'Origin': 'http://toto-info.co',
            'Referer': 'http://toto-info.co/'},proxies = proxy, data=json.dumps(pl))

    #req = s.post(url, headers = , data = json.dumps(playloads))
    print(res)
    return s.text

#def parse(html):

    #soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

def main():

    url = 'http://old.toto-info.co'

    useragents = open("useragents.txt").read().split('\n')
    proxies = open("proxies.txt").read().split('\n')
    proxy = {'http':'http://' + choice(proxies)}
    useragent = {'User-Agent': choice(useragents)}

    try:
        html = get_html(url, useragent)
    except:
        print("----------------------")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `headers` добавьте `'content-type': 'application/json'`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё так просто оказалось @Sergey Gornostaev

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)